# Set right string location c# mysql update

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I think it is a simple fix, but after trying som things i'm confused. I am writing a update command in c# using mysql. To give @todo (see in code) a value from tbtodo, i have tried putting it in the void called "string" _todo, with no succes.

```
private void btBewerk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string _todo)
    {
        if (btBewerk.Text == "Bewerken")
        {
            tbTodo.ReadOnly = false;
            btBewerk.Text = "Opslaan";
            tmCheck.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            db_connection();
            MySqlCommand cmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand();
            cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE `user` SET `todo`=@todo WHERE `username` LIKE '" + _naam + "'";
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todo", _todo);

        }

    }
```

did i put it wrong? or is there another way?

Edit:

I made a private bool, but i still don't know what to put in exactly:

```
private bool Todo_updaten(string _todo)
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand();
        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE `user` SET `todo`=@todo WHERE `username` LIKE '" + _naam + "'";
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todo", _todo);
        cmdUpdate.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader tbupdaten = cmdUpdate.ExecuteReader();
        if (tbupdaten.Read())
        {
            tbTodo.Text = tbupdaten.GetString(0);
            connect.Clone();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

the bool "todo_updaten " gives a error: "HomeFRM.Todo_updaten(string): not all code paths return a value"

Comment: Well you're not actually executing your command, which doesn't help. You should use a parameter for the `username` parameter as well, btw. It's not clear what you mean by "I have tried putting it in the void called string _todo"... (I'd also strongly advise creating a new connection each time you need one - let the connection pool handle it. Use a `using` statement for the connection and the command to dispose of each appropriately.)

Comment: What is `_naam` that you're trying to pass as parameter to SQL?

Comment: put this code"cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todo", _todo); "above your cmdUpdate.CommandText

Comment: @sachin The value that is called "name", so it looks in the table for the users name and edits the todo of him/her

Comment: @JonSkeet tried something, but with an error.

Comment: Well the error you've described is because you're not returning anything if `tbupdaten.Read()` returns `false`... that doesn't really have anything to do with mysql or winforms. (Search for that error message and you'll find lots of hits on SO.)